# meaning of 'Tonight, on a very special Blossom.'

Tags: meaning

This is from a sitcom, *Friends*.

Joey's image on posters for free clinic doesn't serve him very well. So he comes back to Monica's apt. to complain:

> Joey: Set another place for Thanksgiving. My entire family thinks I
> have VD.
>
> Chandler: **Tonight on a very special Blossom.**

What does this last quote of Chandler mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you weren't watching [certain sitcoms during the 90s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_special_episode) (or specifically [Blossom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_(TV_series))) you wouldn't understand this joke.

> Sometimes, sitcoms get real. And in the ‘90s, sitcoms aimed at young people got really real. We called them "very special" episodes, meaning they came with a message and often, a warning.
>
> *Blossom* alone had several "very special" episodes that taught teenagers about marijuana, racism, bulimia and assault.
>
> — [A Comprehensive Guide to *Blossom*'s "Very Special" Episodes](https://www.eonline.com/amp/news/717080/a-comprehensive-guide-to-blossom-s-very-special-episodes)

What Joey says sounds like the setup for such an episode. "VD" means "veneral disease" which is an older name for an STD or STI (sexually transmitted disease or infection).

Comment: As someone whose daughter was addicted to 'Blossom' aged 13, I can tell you that to an adult the show could be very irritating, which adds edge to the joke.

Comment: @Michael Harvey What does 'add edge to sth' mean?

Comment: @ellse - if a joke has 'edge' it has a subversive quality of some kind.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you very much.

Comment: @ellse - subversive because it subverts the convention that media aimed at children, teens, or 'young adults' are by definition admirable, charming, wonderful, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sorry. But I still can't understand exactly what you mean.  You mean 'Friends' makes above Chandler's joke break the common idea that teen-targeting media is, of course, admirable, charming, wonderful, etc.?

Comment: @ellse - maybe it's just my personal feeling that such media can be annoying, patronizing, etc, that makes me perceive an 'edge'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I see. Thank you very much.